# Card ui like google+ or facebook

Tags: android

Are there any sample or library like google+ that cards will be loaded while scroll down. 
Or any other card content ui that is similar to google+, facebook or other apps used ?

Comment: not slidingmenu, just ui/content page design; like card view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the [CardsUI](http://www.androidviews.net/2012/12/cardsui/) project, with its [source code](https://github.com/nadavfima/cardsui-for-android).